# Ruby on Rails options_for_select onchange to call a Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do you setup a select element to change the maximum value of a number field element on a change of value?

I want to change the max value of the passenger number field when the flight ID is changed.

This is my code so far. As you can see, I added the onchange at the end of the select layout.

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :flight_id %>
    <%= form.select :flight_id, options_for_select(Flight.all.map {|flight| [flight.name, flight.id]}, form.object.id), onchange: 'getMaxCapacity()' %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <% qty = @reservation.passengers %>
    <%= form.label :passengers %>
    <%= form.number_field :passengers, :id => 'passengers', min: 1, onchange: "calculateTotalPrice()", oninput: "calculateTotalPrice()" %>
  </div>
```

My Javascript function getMaxCapacity() never gets entered. In the function I am setting the max value of the 'passengers' number field to the capacity variable.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var capacity = {
  <% Flight.all.each do |flight| %>
    '<%= flight.id %>': <%= flight.capacity %>,
  <% end %>
  };

  function getMaxCapacity() {
    document.getElementById('passengers').max = capacity;
  }

  var costs = {
  <% Flight.all.each do |flight| %>
    '<%= flight.id %>': <%= flight.cost %>,
  <% end %>
  };

  function calculateTotalPrice() {
    var price = costs[document.getElementById('reservation_flight_id').value];
    document.getElementById('cost').value = document.getElementById('passengers').value * price;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The signature of the [`FormBuilder#select`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-select) looks like this:

```
select(method, choices = nil, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)
```

This means `html_options` are the fourth parameter. Because you do not have any `options` for the `select` method you need to pass an empty hash as a third parameter.

```
<%= form.select(
      :flight_id, 
      options_for_select(Flight.all.map {|flight| [flight.name, flight.id]}, form.object.id), 
      {},                                 # empty options
      onchange: 'getMaxCapacity()' %>.    # here the HTML options
```